# How to intensify the structure: "someone is jealous of someone else"

Tags: intensifiers

How you would intensify the following sentence:

> - He is jealous of me.

I'm not sure, but which one of the following sentences works here:

> - He is a **serious** jealous of me.
> - He is a **real** jealous of me.
> - He is a **severe** jealous of me.

I was wondering if you could help me to discover what sentence is in common use to be said here.

Comment: *very* jealous?

Comment: He is _intensely_ jealous of me?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how jealous you want to make this person out to be, **insanely** is often used to intensify *jealous* in this context.

> He is **insanely jealous** of me.

The meaning being that the person is jealous almost to the point of being crazy.

Answer (score 3):

You would intensify *jealous*, which doesn't need the article, so there's no reason for it to be there:

> - He is **seriously** jealous of me
> - He is **really** jealous of me
> - He is **severely** jealous of me
> - He is **very** jealous of me

It's possible *seriously* might be a bit too casual, and *severely* isn't quite right, and it has a different meaning which might be confusing. The best way to go is *really* or *very*.

Comment: You could do worse than refer to Shakespeare, who coined so many sayings 400 years ago that are a vital part of English to this day. In Othello, Act 3, scene 3 he personified jealousy as "the green-ey'd monster, which doth mock The meat it feeds on."

Could you imagine a more intense jealousy than "That green-eyed monster, his jealousy for me, eats at his very spleen"?

And dropping a little Shakespeare along the way could not fail to impress!

Comment: It's worth noting that in some dialects, "He is real jealous of me" is okay in informal contexts. Unfortunately, without the right stress pattern, it could be thought of as a mistake made by a non-native speaker.

Comment: @MarkS. Yeah, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

All the sentences presented by the OP are not correct grammatically.

The word "jealous" is an adjective, not a noun. An adverb modifies an adjective, but the OP has used adjectives serious, real and severe instead of the adverbs seriously, really and severely to modify the jealous.

None of the adverbs mentioned above are common in use though you can use them.  You can also use other adverbs such as very, extremely, insanely, madly, too.  The use depends on the extent of the intensity you want to indicate.

However, the most commoly used adverb going with jealous is "very".

He's very jealous of me.